# How to convert FlowDocument to string?

Tags: c#, wpf, converters, flowdocument

[image]

1) How to convert FlowDocument to string?

2) How to convert my string to FlowDocument?

FlowDocument contains text and pictures.

The text in the string should be preserved. `Text12345`

Pictures must be converted. For example, encoded: `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAYAAACOEfKtAAAABHNCSV`

```
Text12345
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAYAAACOEfKtAAAABHNCSV
Text67890


<text>
    Text12345
    <encoded_image>
        iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAYAAACOEfKtAAAABHNCSV
    </encoded_image>
    Text67890
</text>
```

XAML:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="textrich" >
    <FlowDocument >
        <Paragraph/>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Why don't you enumerate _YourRichTextBox.Document.Blocks_? If it is a TextRun, get the string, if it is something else, convert it to a string.

Comment: How?...........

Comment: To show how, I think you should be more specific. What do you mean by "Pictures must be converted"? do you want help on that, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way for getting the text of a *RichTextBox* is by using a *TextRange*:

```
string rtb = new TextRange(rtb .Document.ContentStart, rtb .Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

In your case, you want to deal with different Blocks and Inlines, differently. You can enumerate them. Something like this:

```
var res = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Block r in rtb.Document.Blocks)
    {
        if (r is Paragraph) 
            foreach (Inline i in ((Paragraph)r).Inlines)
                if (i is Run)
                {
                    res.Append(r.ToString());
                }
                else if (i is InlineUIContainer)
                {
                     res.Append(ConvertToString((Image)((InlineUIContainer)i).Child)); // you should create ConvertToString() method 
                } 

   }
```